# Añadir estilo a un elemento al hacer hover al elemento padre

Tags: css

Tengo un `<div>` dentro del cual hay un `<p>` con un texto. Como puedo hacer para que al pasar el cursor por encima del `<div>` se aplique un efecto de subrayado `text-decoration: underline` al `<p>` usando CSS

Este es mi código HTML:

```
<div id="addNewColumn"  style="width: 200px; height: 300px; border: 1px dashed green; border-radius: 5px; border-width: 2px; margin: 20px; cursor: pointer">    
    <p id="newColLink"   style="text-align: center;">   Underline on hover </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para aplicar lo que deseas haciendo el hover en un elemento PERO asignandole los estilos a otro elemento podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```css
#addNewColumn:hover p{
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<div id="addNewColumn"  style="width: 200px; height: 300px; border: 1px dashed green; border-radius: 5px; border-width: 2px; margin: 20px; cursor: pointer">    
    <p id="newColLink"   style="text-align: center;">   Underline on hover </p>
</div>
```

Con el selector `#addNewColumn:hover p` estás diciendo que a todos los elementos `<p>` que estén dentro del `div#addNewColumn` se les aplique cierto estilo al momento de pasar el mouse por encima.

**NOTA:** los estilos inline (como los estás usando) son una mala práctica en el código, deberías tener una hoja de estilos externa y vincularla al HTML por medio de la etiqueta `<link>`

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que deseas es que al pasar el `mouse` por el `div` aplique el estilo `text-decoration: underline;` prueba el siguiente `codigo`.

```css
#addNewColumn {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#addNewColumn p {
    text-align: center;
}
#addNewColumn:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="addNewColumn">    
        <p id="newColLink">   Underline on hover </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sí aplica un `background:red` al `hover` , se verá claramente que está aplicando el estilo al `div` padre más no al párrafo . sí modifica esto tendrá mi +1 por remover el estilo inline.

Answer (score 2):

Aplica desde `CSS` el `hover` al padre `#addNewColumn:hover` pero la regla `CSS` se aplicará al hijo *(p)*

```css
#addNewColumn{
width: 200px; 
height: 300px; 
border: 1px dashed green;
}
#newColLink{
text-align: center;
}
#addNewColumn:hover p{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="addNewColumn" >    
    <p id="newColLink"> Underline on hover </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu body lo dejas como lo tienes:

```
<div id="addNewColumn"  style="width: 200px; height: 300px; border: 1px dashed green; border-radius: 5px; border-width: 2px; margin: 20px; cursor: pointer">    
    <p id="newColLink"   style="text-align: center;">  
        Underline on hover
    </p>
</div>
```

En tu fichero css que tendrás vinculado a tu html, añades lo siguiente:

```
    #addNewColumn:hover p {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Comment: Nunca es aconsejable utilizar estilos inline, no se debería dejar el body con esos estilos en las etiquetas!!! > los estilos inline (como los estás usando) son una mala práctica en el código, deberías tener una hoja de estilos externa y vincularla al HTML por medio de la etiqueta <link>

Comment: Calmate, es un ejemplo solo para que pueda probarlo en su html rapidamente en caso de estar utilizando css interno. Por supuesto que yo tambien aconsejo utilizar css externo. Actualizare la respuesta para evitar "malentendidos"..