# Alterar elemento hijo al hacer hover en padre

Tags: html, css, twig

Necesito que al  hacer `hover` sobre el div con `class="item"` la imagen haga el `transition` que está puesto.

Tal y como lo tengo puesto, la imagen solo se "transforma" si hago hover en ella pero no si lo hago en el div.

He visto esta otra pregunta: [Añadir estilo a un elemento al hacer hover al elemento padre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115836/a%C3%B1adir-estilo-a-un-elemento-al-hacer-hover-al-elemento-padre), pero no me ha servido.

```css
.img_block .noticias_imagen {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.img_block:hover .noticias_imagen {
  transform: rotate(25deg) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="img_block img_blockG">
    <img class="noticias_imagen" src="http://segurosbaratos.motorgiga.com/uploads/comparador_seguros_de_coche.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel_body">
    <div class="team_title">
      <h6>{{ noticia.titulo }}</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="team_desc">{{ noticia.desc|raw }}</div>
    <div class="team_icons_wrapper"><a class="btn btn-default" role="button" href="{{ noticia.link }}" target="_blank">{{ "Sigue.leyendo"|trans }} &raquo;</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No lo entendí muy bien .. no te valdria con `.item:hover ` en vez de `.img_block:hover `?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cuando hagas hover en item quieres cambiar una propiedad de la imagen entiendo, no?

En ese caso te serviría con:

```
    .item:hover .noticias_imagen {
       transition: transform 0.4s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el selector de la regla que contiene la propiedad transform. Esta propiedad esta aplicada a la clase .img_block y no a .item